The same command runs perfectly when executed directly on the Linux server, but it fails when called from the Java program when use selenium
I have a Python script that uses pyhtml2pdf:

import os
import sys
from pyhtml2pdf import converter

def convert_html_to_pdf(html_path, pdf_path):
    absolute_html_path = os.path.abspath(html_path)
    converter.convert(f'file:///{absolute_html_path}', pdf_path, 60, False, 0, False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: python3 test.py <html_path> <pdf_path>")
    else:
        html_path = sys.argv[1]
        pdf_path = sys.argv[2]
        convert_html_to_pdf(html_path, pdf_path)

When I run the command directly on a Linux server:
DISPLAY=:99 python3 test.py 298.html 298.pdf

it executes perfectly, and 298.pdf is generated. However, when I try to run this command from within a Java program using:
String comds = "DISPLAY=:99 python3 test.py 298.html 298.pdf";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comds);

I encounter the error:
2024-09-27 11:33:14 - ERROR>Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-09-27 11:33:14 - ERROR>Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-09-27 11:33:14 - ERROR>  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
2024-09-27 11:33:14 - ERROR>    convert_html_to_pdf(html_path, pdf_path)
2024-09-27 11:33:14 - ERROR>  File "test.py", line 7, in convert_html_to_pdf
2024-09-27 11:33:14 - ERROR>    converter.convert(f'file:///{absolute_html_path}', pdf_path, 20, False, 0, False)
2024-09-27 11:33:14 - ERROR>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyhtml2pdf/converter.py", line 39, in convert
2024-09-27 11:33:14 - ERROR>    source, timeout, install_driver, print_options)
2024-09-27 11:33:14 - ERROR>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyhtml2pdf/converter.py", line 79, in __get_pdf_from_html
2024-09-27 11:33:14 - ERROR>    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=webdriver_options)
2024-09-27 11:33:14 - ERROR>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
2024-09-27 11:33:14 - ERROR>    self.service.start()
2024-09-27 11:33:14 - ERROR>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
2024-09-27 11:33:14 - ERROR>    self.assert_process_still_running()
2024-09-27 11:33:14 - ERROR>  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
2024-09-27 11:33:14 - ERROR>    % (self.path, return_code)
2024-09-27 11:33:14 - ERROR>selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -11
2024-09-27 11:33:14 - ERROR>

How can I resolve this issue?
chromedriver -v
ChromeDriver 129.0.6668.70


I would start checking that the command is being run with the correct working directory so it can find 298.html (or try with an absolute path, but I do not work with python)

DISPLAY=:99 is not a command Java handles, it should be interpreted by a shell. You need cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "DISPLAY=:99 ..." or set environment variable using ProcessBuilder

Directly setting DISPLAY=:99 in your Java code might not work as intended. It's better to ensure your X11 environment is properly configured for your Java application and let it pick up the DISPLAY variable automatically.
Set the DISPLAY environment variable before executing the command:
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MyPythonTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String[] command = new String[]{"/Users/xxx/IdeaProjects/test/venv/bin/Python", "/Users/xxx/IdeaProjects/test/test.py", "/Users/xxx/IdeaProjects/test/298.html", "/Users/xxx/IdeaProjects/test/298.pdf"};
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, new String[]{"DISPLAY=99"});

    String line;

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder stdOutput = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        stdOutput.append(line).append("\n");
    }

    BufferedReader errorReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
    StringBuilder errOutput = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = errorReader.readLine()) != null) {
        errOutput.append(line).append("\n");
    }

    int exitCode = process.waitFor();
    if (exitCode != 0) {
        System.err.println("Script exited with error code: " + exitCode);
        System.out.println("Script error output: " + errOutput);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Script std output: " + stdOutput);
    }
}
}


some points: 1) empty space at the start of command; 2) exec(String) is deprecated - javadoc: "Deprecated. This method is error-prone and should not be used, the corresponding method exec(String[]) or ProcessBuilder should be used instead. ..."

In general it is better not to use setProperty. Environment variables can be overridden per invocation of both ProcessBuilder and the deprecated Runtime.exec. Also not consuming stderr can cause sub-process to freeze
